# Save button does not fire code behind event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

This is a simple MVC4 application with single drop down list.  When I click the Save button an event for SaveWorkRequestDetails should fire, seen below as the [HttpPost], but it doesn't for some reason.  I am seeing a 500 error stating that myMachine:12345/WorkRequest/SaveWorkRequestDetails cannot be found when I hit the Save button.  See bottom of post for picture of Console window in Chrome.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    _model = new WorkRequestViewModel()
    {
        WorkSections = GetWorkSections()
    };

    return View(_model);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveWorkRequestDetails(WorkRequestViewModel viewModel)
{
    // TODO: Save logic goes here
    return Json(new {});
}
```

This is the WorkRequest.js file which should fire the Save event.  This does trigger said event IF I DON'T include _model in the return of the View from the ActionResult Index() above, however, the alert seen in the WorkRequest.js file in beforeSend has 'null' when I do that.  Clearly, this isn't the intended behavior because I do want those values and the Save button to trigger the [HttpPost].

```
var WorkRequest = {

PrepareKo: function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            element.onchange = function () {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable(new Date(element.value));
            }
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(observable);
            if ((typeof valueUnwrapped == 'string' || valueUnwrapped instanceof String) &&
                         valueUnwrapped.indexOf('/Date') === 0) {
                var parsedDate = WorkRequest.ParseJsonDate(valueUnwrapped);
                element.value = parsedDate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" +
                  parsedDate.getDate() + "/" + parsedDate.getFullYear();
                observable(parsedDate);
            }
        }
    };
},

ParseJsonDate: function (jsonDate) {
    return new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
},

BindUIwithViewModel: function (viewModel) {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
},

EvaluateJqueryUI: function () {
    $('.dateInput').datepicker();
},

RegisterUIEventHandlers: function () {

    $('#Save').click(function (e) {

        // Check whether the form is valid. Note: Remove this check, if you are not using HTML5
        if (document.forms[0].checkValidity()) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: WorkRequest.SaveUrl,
                data: ko.toJSON(WorkRequest.ViewModel),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // Display loading image
                    alert(ko.toJSON(WorkRequest.ViewModel));
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    // Handle the response here.
                },
                complete: function () {
                    // Hide loading image.
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // Handle error.
                }
            });
        }
    });
  },
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  WorkRequest.PrepareKo();
  WorkRequest.BindUIwithViewModel(WorkRequest.ViewModel);
  WorkRequest.EvaluateJqueryUI();
  WorkRequest.RegisterUIEventHandlers();
});
```

This is my Index.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities
@model WorkRequest.ViewModel.WorkRequestViewModel
@using WorkRequest.Helper

@section styles{
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
  <link href="~/Content/WorkRequest.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}

@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Application/WorkRequest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    WorkRequest.SaveUrl = '@Url.Action("SaveWorkRequestDetails", "WorkRequest")';
    WorkRequest.ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
</script>
}
<form>
  <div class="mainWrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Work Sections: 
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.DropDownList("WorkSections", Model.WorkSections, new {data_bind="value: WorkRequest.ViewModel.WorkSections"})
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<input id="Save" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Now this entire sample is based on a demo I found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/657981/ASP-NET-MVC-4-with-Knockout-Js and I was able to get it working just fine until I tried to populate my own drop down list.  I am able to get the data for my drop down list and populate my SelectList without issues and see it on my form.

My View Model

```
public class WorkRequestViewModel
{
    public SelectList WorkSections { get; set; }
}
```

I have confirmed this SelectList is populated and I see the items in my drop down list but the demo application uses two custom classes to make the controls in the Index.cshtml page observable so that knockout can do its thing...

HtmlExtensions.cs

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// To create an observable HTML Control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">The model object</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">The property name</typeparam>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper">The <see cref="HtmlHelper<T>"/></param>
    /// <param name="expression">The property expression</param>
    /// <param name="controlType">The <see cref="ControlTypeConstants"/></param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes">The html attributes</param>
    /// <returns>Returns computed HTML string.</returns>
    public static IHtmlString ObservableControlFor<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel,
            TProperty>> expression, string controlType =
            ControlTypeConstants.TextBox, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        string jsObjectName = null;
        string generalWidth = null;

        // This will be useful, if the same extension has
        // to share with multiple pages (i.e. each with different view models).
        switch (metaData.ContainerType.Name)
        {
            case "WorkRequestViewModel":
                // Where WorkRequest is the Javascript object name (namespace in theory). 
                jsObjectName = "WorkRequest.ViewModel.";
                generalWidth = "width: 380px";
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception(string.Format("The container type {0} is not supported yet.",
                                    metaData.ContainerType.Name));
        }

        var propertyObject = jsObjectName + metaData.PropertyName;

        TagBuilder controlBuilder = null;

        // Various control type creation.
        switch (controlType)
        {
            case ControlTypeConstants.TextBox:
                controlBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("type", "text");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("style", generalWidth);
                break;
            case ControlTypeConstants.Html5NumberInput:
                controlBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("type", "number");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("style", generalWidth);
                break;
            case ControlTypeConstants.Html5UrlInput:
                controlBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("type", "url");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("style", generalWidth);
                break;
            case ControlTypeConstants.TextArea:
                controlBuilder = new TagBuilder("textarea");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("rows", "5");
                break;
            case ControlTypeConstants.DropDownList:
                controlBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("class", "dropDownList");
                break;
            case ControlTypeConstants.JqueryUIDateInput:
                controlBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("type", "text");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("style", generalWidth);
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("class", "dateInput");
                controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("data-bind", "date: " + propertyObject);
                // date is the customized knockout binding handler. Check PrepareKo method of Person.

                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception(string.Format("The control type {0} is not supported yet.", controlType));
        }

        controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("id", metaData.PropertyName);
        controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("name", metaData.PropertyName);

        // Check data-bind already exists, add if not.
        if (!controlBuilder.Attributes.ContainsKey("data-bind"))
        {
            controlBuilder.Attributes.Add("data-bind", "value: " + propertyObject);
        }

        // Merge provided custom html attributes. This overrides the previously defined attributes, if any.
        if (htmlAttributes != null)
        {
            controlBuilder.MergeAttributes(
                HtmlExtensions.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes), true);
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(controlBuilder.ToString());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To convert '_' into '-'.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes">The html attributes.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns converted <see cref="RouteValueDictionary"/>.</returns>
    private static RouteValueDictionary AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(object htmlAttributes)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary result = new RouteValueDictionary();
        if (htmlAttributes != null)
        {
            foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor property in
                        System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(htmlAttributes))
            {
                result.Add(property.Name.Replace('_', '-'), property.GetValue(htmlAttributes));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

ViewModelConstants.cs

```
public static class ControlTypeConstants
{
    public const string TextBox = "TextBox";
    public const string TextArea = "TextArea";
    public const string CheckBox = "CheckBox";
    public const string DropDownList = "DropDownList";
    public const string Html5NumberInput = "Html5NumberInput";
    public const string Html5UrlInput = "Html5UrlInput";
    public const string Html5DateInput = "Html5DateInput";
    public const string JqueryUIDateInput = "JqueryUIDateInput";
}
```

So the root of my issue is that once the UI is successfully populated with a drop down list containing values, I select one and hit the save button and I see the alert display what is in the model but the Save button is never triggered.

In the example provided from CodeProject a control has this custom ObservableControlFor after @Html, see above class HtmlExtensions.  This is what it looks like: @Html.ObservableControlFor(model => model.Name, ControlTypeConstants.TextBox) so I tried to do the same in my example but I don't know how to turn @Html.DropDownList("myList") into @Html.ObservableControlFor...  I tried the following @Html.ObservableControlFor(model => model.WorkSections, ControlTypeConstants.DropDownList) but the control is never rendered to the UI and I get the same 500 error as before.

[image: Console from Chrome]

I have tried ViewData in my @Html control but the function is expecting something like model => model.WorkSections

[image: Error]

HTML Markup from View Source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title></title>
  <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/Content/WorkRequest.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <div class="mainWrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Work Sections: 
            </td>
            <td>


                <div class="dropDownList" data-bind="value: WorkRequest.ViewModel.WorkSections" id="WorkSections" name="WorkSections"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<input id="Save" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Application/WorkRequest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    WorkRequest.SaveUrl = '/WorkRequest/SaveWorkRequestDetails';
    WorkRequest.ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({"WorkSectionId":0,"WorkSections":[{"Selected":false,"Text":"308:IPACS","Value":"308"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"312:IPACS","Value":"312"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"301:IPACS","Value":"301"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"316:IPACS","Value":"316"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"307:IPACS","Value":"307"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"318:IPACS","Value":"318"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"313:IPACS","Value":"313"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"319:IPACS","Value":"319"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"315:IPACS","Value":"315"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"310:IPACS","Value":"310"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"300:IPACS","Value":"300"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"302:IPACS","Value":"302"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"304:IPACS","Value":"304"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"306:IPACS","Value":"306"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"309:IPACS","Value":"309"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"305:STORM","Value":"305"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"311:IPACS","Value":"311"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"317:IPACS","Value":"317"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"303:IPACS","Value":"303"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"314:IPACS","Value":"314"}]});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind shortening down this to expose just the problem? It's a bit hard to digest such long text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may lie in these two lines of code:

```
data: ko.toJSON(WorkRequest.ViewModel),
contentType: 'application/json',
```

You should remove the `contentType` line and change:

```
data: $.param(WorkRequest.ViewModel)
```

The issue issue is you are trying to pass the server JSON and it by default accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  `contentType` dictates the format passed back from the server.  `dataType` is what you are looking for however by default .Net MVC wants the default.

If this doesnt work it would be helpful to see the stack trace from the exception that is causing your 500 error, although I would expect the issue is that your model is not binding since your data is in the wrong format.

Comment: I do see the data in the alert now so that appears to have solved half the issue.  Any advice on the getting the drop down list working with @Html.ObservableControlFor(model => model.WorkSections)?  If I could just put "myList" in for model => model.WorkSections it would work but that function won't allow that syntax.

Comment: `model.WorkSections` and `ViewData["myList"]` are the same so why does it matter?

Comment: Because the syntax of @Html.ObservableControlFor requires something like model => model.WorkSections.  It will break if I try "myList"

Comment: And the Save button remains un-triggered.

Comment: I have added a screen capture to the thread above so you can see what happens when I try to add ViewData["myList"]

Comment: @BrianEvans that is not going to work because it has to be an expression, my point is why cant you just use Model.WorkSections, according to your code it is identical?  If I am missing something, you have two choices, 1) add a property to your ViewModel that reflects what is now ViewData["myList"] or create  an overloaded method for `ObservableControlFor` that accepts your list.  It sounds to me like you are trying to fit a square peg through a round hole so I would try a different approach.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are saying here.  I do have public SelectList WorkSections { get; set; } in my ViewModel and when I try and go this way: @Html.ObservableControlFor(model => model.WorkSections) I see nothing.  If I use this: @Html.DropDownList("myList") I see my data but the Save button doesn't work in either scenario and I get that 500 error again, right back where I started.  I appreciate SO MUCH your help, I am really struggling here.

Comment: ViewData["myList"] and viewModel.WorkSections are both of type System.Web.Mvc.SelectList. Both are populated and returned from the ActionResult Index(), they have data.  I can even see WorkSections in intellisense when I type model => model. in the Index.cshtml page.  I just understand what the issue is here.
'

Comment: I've tried all sorts of things here, I've gotten as far as I can.  I'm at your mercy.

Comment: @BrianEvans when you put `(model => model.WorkSections, ControlTypeConstants.DropDownList)` can you look in the source an see if anything is rendered?  I looked at the logic of that extension method and when you put the DropDownList constant, it is creating a div with a class of dropDownList.  This leads me to believe that they are not rendering a `select` tag but rather a custom dropdown box that requires CSS and JavaScript.  It is possible that you havent included all of the JS needed to drive that select box?  Anyway, see if something is rendered in the source and post it.

Comment: @BrianEvans, there is nothing in the code that makes that div a dropdownlist what I would do, is go down the route of using DropDownList("WorkSections", Model.WorkSections, new {data_bind = "value: WorkSections"}) (check this out for the exact syntax: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).  Essentially you should manually set the `data-bind` attribute that KO uses to bind your select option to your viewmodel.  I am not a KO expeert and have always struggled with select lists and KO, but that link should contain everything you need to make it work.

Comment: That is a really good idea @marteljn, I am updating the code above with the markup.  A <div> was created!

Comment: ok, @marteljn, I put this in my markup: @Html.DropDownList("WorkSections", Model.WorkSections, new {data_bind="value: WorkRequest.ViewModel.WorkSections"}) and when the alert box appears I see the value of the selected item from my drop down so the ONLY thing left is to get the [HttpPost] SaveWorkRequestDetails to fire.  So, I opened the Console (F12 in Chrome) and I still see that same 500 Server error.  Thoughts on solving this last tiny part?